# Multithreaded server with boost.Asio

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, boost, boost-asio

I'm trying to make a server that receives many connections and handle it.
I think it's better if i put each connection in a thread, but I don't know how to do it, cause  i still don't know how i tell my class "i receive a new connection, put it into a thread". I'm very confused and still don't found it in none of other posts here. Please, help me.

obs.: I had a hint which create a bunch of connections and so wait for the client, but i don't want to do this, I want to create a connection only if there is someone trying to enter in my server.

Comment: is it a requirement that you need to use boost::asio?

Comment: no, but it's the simplest way I found.

Comment: You might want to check out ZeroMQ (http://www.zeromq.org/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Boost::Asio documentation's [asynchronous TCP daytime server tutorial](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tutdaytime3.html) describes exactly how to write such a server.

Further, there are a number of multithreaded [examples](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples.html) in among all the rest.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the examples in the asio documentation. Following example does what you want:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/echo/blocking_tcp_echo_server.cpp
This creates a new thread per connection and uses the blocking calls.

Note that you can also use the asynchronous calls and do everything in one thread. The example for that would be:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/echo/async_tcp_echo_server.cpp

Comment: This example doesn't create more than 1 thread. I think i was misunderstood... I just want some way to listen until a new connection has been done, so, I prepare to wait for other connection and so on. But i've been studying and I notice people don't do this with boost... It's allright?

Comment: No, the blocking example does create 1 thread per connection. After `accept` a new thread is created. Entry point of the new thread is the  `session` function. When the thread object `t` goes out of scope it detaches, but the thread until the `session` function returns. The lifetime of the socket is managed by a `shared_ptr`